# Salesforce Softphone - remove popout/expand icon

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to find a way to remove popout/expand icon from my salesforce softphone in Utility bar. The right-most icon in below attached screenshot.

[image]

Following are available methods to access CTI application, some of which can be used to change title, icon, width, height etc of softphone but there is not method to remove expand icon, nor there is ant in App setup page.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_methods_intro_lightning.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hide/disable that popout icon by adding this attribute to the lightning component: `<aura:attribute name="supportsPopOut" type="Boolean" default="false" />` or by calling the javascript method `disableUtilityPopOut();`

Comment: How to call this function form CTI app